# break if variable has specific value

Tags: php

I try to listen for the value of a variable and execute some code if it has a specific value.

e.g. I execute the function `element()` inside a switch statement and I have to execute `break` if the value of `$element` is false.

At the moment I do it like this:

```
switch(strtolower($testcase)) {
    case 'test':
        $element = $sel->element("class name", "btn-primary", true);
        if ($element == false) { break; }
        $element->click("");
...

public function element($using, $value, $takeScreenshot=false, $customMessage="")
{   
    try {
        $element = $this->driver->element($using, $value);

    } catch(PHPWebDriver_UnhandledWebDriverError $exception) {

        $msg = "<b>PHPWebDriver_UnhandledWebDriverError: $using</b> is "
                . "not a valid value for the parameter <b>\$using</b>!";

        if ($customMessage !== "") {
            $msg = "<b>$customMessage</b><br>$msg";
        }

        $this->setMessage(1, $msg, $exception, $takeScreenshot, $value);
        return false;

    } catch(PHPWebDriver_NoSuchElementWebDriverError $exception) {
        $msg = "<b>PHPWebDriver_NoSuchElementWebDriverError:</b> No "
                . "Element with <b>'$using'</b> and value <b>'$value'</b> found !";

        if ($customMessage !== "") {
            $msg = "<b>$customMessage</b><br>$msg";
        }

        $this->setMessage(1, $msg, $exception, $takeScreenshot, $value);
        return false;
    }

    return $element;
}
```

But I would like to simplify it so that the line `if ($element == false) { break; }` is not needed anymore. e.g.

```
switch(strtolower($testcase)) {
    case 'test':
        $element = $this->element("class name", "btn-primary", true);
        $element->click("");
...
```

I tried to `return break;` but this failed. Is there another way? e.g. can I add an EventListener which executes `break` automatically in the switch case if the value of `$element` is false?

Comment: returning a break, even if it worked, would make `element` highly coupled to your switch statement, which is usually a bad design.

Comment: You are going to have to tell us why its there. And then what you want to do instead?

Comment: THis is PHP code, there are no Event Listeners

Comment: @RiggsFolly, It is there to stop executing the restcode, because it would not make any sense to call `$element->click("");` if the value of `$element` is false.

Comment: Maybe `if ( ! is_object($element) ) { ... } else {}`

Comment: What does the rest of your `switch` look like? Are you setting (or attempting to set) `$element` in each case? If so, then you could probably conditionally call `$element->click("")` _after_ the switch.

Comment: @PatrickQ, I am executing selenium php-webdriver commands in the switch case. I need to break as soons as the value of $element is false, because in this case the testcase failed.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to do too much directly in your `switch`. Personally, I think you should consider wrapping what you're currently doing in each `case` within functions, and then simply have the body of the `case` call the correct function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building functions, it's usually best to design them to be de-coupled, not coupled.  This means, element() shouldn't care about what is calling it.

Therefore, attempting to break a switch from within element() would be a bad programming design.

If element() should always stop execution when it hits a certain spot, regardless of what called it, you should consider throwing an exception.  However, this won't simplify the code in your switch statement as you'd have to use try, catch blocks.

With that said, since PHP allows assignments in conditionals, you could simplify the code you have written as:

```
    if ($element = $sel->element("class name", "btn-primary", true)) {
         $element->click("");
    }
```